# Xcode 7: order results in Open Quickly search results, showing Swift files first

Tags: xcode, xcode7

In Xcode 7, is there a way to order the search results of the `Open Quickly` command?

The goal is to show Swift files first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue captured on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43550). As of now, it doesn't appear possible to configure Xcode such that Swift files get listed first in the search results. Argh.

The best workaround as suggested in one of the posts is to leverage the fuzzy search algorithm in Xcode. That is, if you're searching for `DirectoryViewController.swift`, type `dvc` and that will list the Swift file first (presumably if there are no other project components named `dvc`).